# Как протестировать junit вывод в консоль?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

```
public void add(Item item) {
    if (!item.header.equals(null)) {
        this.items[this.index] = item;
        this.index++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please header enter.");
    }
}
```

хочу добавить тест на

```
} else {
    System.out.println("Please header enter.");
```

используя конструкцию

```
assertThat(???, is(???));
```

Но что сюда подставлять если у меня консольное приложение? А метод void?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не завязывайте приложение на логирование в консоль. Используйте отдельный объект-логгер, которому будуте передавать строку и уровень логирования. Это стандарт, так делается во множестве крупных проектов.

Приложения работают на серверах, там некому пялиться в монитор и читать логи, поэтому сообщения пишутся туда, куда удобно разработчикам и админам — в файл, в сокет, отправляются по http, что угодно ещё. Могут и в stdout, как в вашем случае, но должен быть выбор. И если в stdout, то `System.out.println` находится в коде логгера, а не в том месте, где происходит логирование.

И когда вам нужно будет протестировать логгер, вы просто подсунете вместо него тестовый объект, в котором будете проверять, что такой-то метод с такой-то строкой был вызван.

Уже есть множество написанных логгеров, я когда-то использовал log4j, но не могу сравнить с другими.

Comment: Я понял что в данном задании мне видимо не надо проверять это место. Но я буду иметь в виду что работой с логом должна заниматься отдельная часть программы.

Comment: @Павел хорошо. И вы молодец, что пишете юнит-тесты.

Comment: Только TDD! только хардкор!)))

Comment: И всё таки, есть какой-нибудь способ автоматически проверять, что программа выводит в консоль? Вот в принципе есть?